# SQL getdate issue with month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i need help on my little problem.

```
 SELECT FORMAT(ServiceDate, 'dd-MM-yyy") AS ServiceDate
 FROM Services
   WHERE Day(ServiceDate) BETWEEN '1' AND Day(getdate() -2)
   AND Month(ServiceDate) = 
     CASE 
        WHEN Day(getdate()) <=2 
        THEN Month(getdate() -1 
        ELSE Month(getdate()) 
     END
   AND Year(ServiceDate) = Year(getdate())
```

Now the problem is the first and the second of the Month.
The query don't use the last month. It shows the actual month.

I hope its clear what i need.

if we have the 01-06-2016 and i need minus 2, so the query must give me back to the day 30-05-2016

big THX

the output for today with this query

[output query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CADMn.png)

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (getdate etc are product specific functions.)

Comment: We need a little help trying to understand what your query is trying to do.

Comment: Do not extract date parts. Use Date arithmetic of your DBMS.

Comment: its a service database, he had much columns. so he have three filters to search for successful services. once per day my program creates a file and send it as an attached csv in an email. now i need all from this month minus 2 days. yesterday and today the service didn't need
this is not the complete query its only a part of that what i'm using

Comment: I don't understand the logic. If the current date is past day 2, get all the records between the 1st and 2 days ago, but if the current date is day 1 or 2, what should you return?

Comment: so it returns the last moth. if the date its 1. it returns form 1-29 last month. its the 2. it returns the 1-30 last month and so on

Comment: I have to say with all honesty I have no idea what you are asking.  Show us a sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sql-server, you need to use `DATEADD(Day,  -2, GETDATE())` for subtracting 2 days from current date.

Comment: i try it, but it didn't work for me. the query shows me the 29-06-2016

Comment: You must be just extracting Day part out of it.

Comment: @Zohar: GETDATE() - 2 is not among the best of practices you use

Comment: @chaos: correct, it's not best practice but still is possible and that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the logic now:

- If the current day is the **1st** of the month, get all the records from the start of *previous month*, until 2 days before it ends.
- If the current day is the **2nd** of the month, get all the records from the start of the *previous month* until one day before it ends.
- If the current day is the **3rd** of the month or higher, get all the records from the beginning of the *current month* until 2 days ago.

Since you are using the `FORMAT()` function that was introduced in 2012 version, you can also use the [`EOMONTH()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) function that was introduced in the same version.
This function returns the date of the end of the month of the date it receives as an argument, and also have a useful optional second argument that specifies the numbers of months to add to the date passed to the function.
Using this function will allow you to write your query without using any functions on the `ServiceDate` column, thus enabling the use of any indexes defined on this column.

```
DECLARE @Now datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT FORMAT(ServiceDate, 'dd-MM-yyy') AS ServiceDate
FROM Services
WHERE (
    DAY(@Now) <= 2 
    AND ServiceDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Now, -2))
    AND ServiceDate < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@Now)-1), EOMONTH(@Now, -1))
)
OR
(
    DAY(GETDATE()) > 2 
    AND ServiceDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Now, -1))
    AND ServiceDate < DATEADD(DAY, -2, @Now)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You absolutely understand the problem. the implementation runs very well. the output is now the 28-05-2016. but i think i can find out what it is now. thumb up my friend :)

Comment: While the shortcut of date math works it is confusing to read. Aaron Betrand thinks so too. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @SeanLange good point. I usually use dateadd myself, it's a part of the copy n` paste from the original query :-)

Comment: wow, thank you so much. great post. now the output is to the 31. of the previous month PERFECT :)

Comment: @Sean thanks for the blog-post, i will read it to make it better next time

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: Hello, i test it the last days and i had a bit to much rows. So i figure out what the problem is.  the complete statement must be in brace like WHERE ( (DAY...) OR (DAY...) ) otherwise the rows are not correct. now it work perfect. THX for help

Answer (score 0):

Compute enddate as 2 days before getdate() and select data in interval from enddate's first of month and enddate.

```
 SELECT FORMAT(ServiceDate, 'dd-MM-yyy") AS ServiceDate
 FROM Services
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT enddate = DATEADD(D,-2,getdate()) x
   WHERE ServiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,x.enddate),0) AND x.enddate
```